# print string problem in C

Tags: c, string, struct, printf

i have this struct

```
typedef struct tree_node_s{
    char word[20];

    struct tree_node_s *leftp,*rightp;

    }fyllo
```

i want to print the word in a file and im using fprintf
the problem is in PROBLINE

```
void print_inorder(fyllo *riza,FILE *outp){

     if (riza==NULL) return ;
     print_inorder(riza->leftp,outp);
     fprintf("%s",riza->word);  //PROBLINE
     print_inorder(riza->rightp,outp);
                }
```

im compiling and i got this problem

```
tree.c: In function ‘print_inorder’:
tree.c:35: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fprintf’ from incompatible pointer type
```

whats the problem here;

Comment: Don't ignore compiler warning. Include appropriate header file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `fprintf` wrongly. The declaration of this function is

```
 int fprintf(FILE *restrict stream, const char *restrict format, ...);
```

Therefore, you should put the FILE pointer as the first argument (did you notice that you have never actually used `outp` in the function?).  The line should be written as

```
fprintf(outp, "%s", riza->word);
```

Comment: or, as they say RTFM... especially when you've never used the function before :)

Answer (score 3):

The first argument to `fprintf` should be the `FILE*` to print to:

```
fprintf(outp, "%s", riza->word);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
fprintf("%s",riza->word);
```

to

```
fprintf(outp, "%s", riza->word);
```